# XOR encryption can be easily hacked?

Tags: security, encryption, xor

I'm really new to encryption and that kind of stuff. I've just learnt about XOR encryption and don't really understand why it's considered good?
Couldn't the key be cracked if the hacker just knows one character in the database?

Comment: No? Why do you think that? Would help if you explained your thinking as it seems likely you've misunderstood something.

Comment: What do you mean by XOR encryption, the information-theoretically secure one-time pad or computationally secure stream ciphers?

Answer (score 2):

If you had 8 bits of data you wanted to encrypt, and you decided to XOR each of those bits against the results of you sequentially flipping a coin, then the only way those bits could be decrypted again is by someone who knows the results of your coin flips. To anyone else it's impossible to know whether you flipped heads or tails, and so it's impossible to know whether the bit was flipped or not

This is called a [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad), and is cryptographically unbreakable so long as the key is the same length as the data, the key remains a secret, and is only used (as the name implies) one time.

Comment: That is not enough for OTP. First of all, you need to securely transmit the keys before use. That is a huge problem for OTP. Also, The OTP keys must not be re-used otherwise there is a crib-dragging attack.

Comment: @kelalaka I added an edit to clarify the 'one time' aspect.

Answer (score 0):

As you have proposed, if XOR is implemented where the key is one character, the key can be found by knowing one corresponding character in the plaintext and cipher text. Most uses of XOR are with a longer key. If the key is at least the length of the plaintext, then every bit in the plaintext is uniquely paired with a bit in the key, then knowing one character gains you no information about any other character. This usage is called a "one time pad".